# How to save condition to database

Tags: sql, dynamic-sql

I have database. there is table where is column. and column contains conditions `> 10`, `< 10`.

And I want to build procedure, that will create a `select` in loop.

How I can take condition from table and put it in `SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE @condition@`?

Comment: Please tag at most one RDBMS.

Comment: Will the condition always use the same column(s)?

Comment: Sounds like a recipe for SQL injection, unless the values in the column can really be trusted as well as sanitized..

Comment: Are all conditions known when writing the query or can there be conditions added and/or removed all the time? (In the first case you can write the query straight away. In the second case you must build the query dynamically at run time.) What DBMS are you asking this for?

Comment: This sounds like a bad design.  I would re-think the application.